# setting the scrollbar to the table viewer

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am facing one problem in setting the scollbar in tableviewer. I have around thousands of record in one table. That means thousand
rows. I edited the last row and pressed enter. When I press enter, the scrollbar goes up of the table. ie it is going to the first row
of the table.So I have to scrolldown again to see the edited row. How can I make sure that when I press enter the scrollbar should stay there. It should not move from the position where it was
last. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables are scrolled by using following API. You can use any one of them.

```
table.setTopIndex(int rowNo);
table.setSelection(int selection);
table.showSelection();
```

(or)

```
viewer.reveal(Object obj);
```

Hope you get, what you been searching for.